# C# Классы. Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

День добрый!

У меня есть форма с richtextbox, есть класс который я использую для авторизации с помощью библиотеки селениум:

```js
class Authenticator 
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;
        private SendMsgLogBox _sendMsgLogBox; 
      
      public Authenticator(IWebDriver driver)
                    {
            _driver = driver;
        }
      
              public Authenticator()
        {
          _sendMsgLogBox = new SendMsgLogBox(null);
        }

        public void Authenticate(string login, string password)
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.111.com/accounts/login/");
            _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='username']")).SendKeys(login);
            _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']")).SendKeys(password);
            _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
             _sendMsgLogBox.AddMsg("TEST"); // тут возникает ошибка
           
            try
            {
                String err = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#slfErrorAlert")).Text;
                Console.WriteLine(err);
              
            }
            catch (Exception) {

         
                Console.WriteLine("log and pass is good"); }
        }
   
   

    }
```

И есть отдельный класс, который будет выполнять действия с richtextbox в главной форме:

```js
class SendMsgLogBox
    {
        Form1 _form;
        

        public SendMsgLogBox(Form1 form)
        {
            this._form = form;
        }
        public void AddMsg(string text)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            _form.richTextBox1.Text+=dt+" "+text+ Environment.NewLine;
            _form.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = _form.richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            _form.richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }
```

Когда я пытаюсь с класса Authenticator с помощью класса SendMsgLogBox добавить строчку

```js
_sendMsgLogBox.AddMsg("TEST");
```

в своей форме - возникает ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.". Я так полагаю, это как-то связанно с моим слабым понимаем классов. Подскажите решение, пожалуйста.

Сама форма:

```js
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

       private Authenticator _authenticator;
      
        IWebDriver web;
           
        public Form1()
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--headless"); //проверить IWebDriver web; на уровень выше сунул
            web = new ChromeDriver(@"D:/");
            web.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
           _authenticator = new Authenticator(web);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String login=textBox1.Text;
            String password=textBox2.Text;

              _authenticator.Authenticate(login, password);
            
        }
          
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробрасывайте зависимость в конструктор, вот так например

```
class Authenticator
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;
    private SendMsgLogBox _sendMsgLogBox;

    public Authenticator(IWebDriver driver, SendMsgLogBox sendMsgLogBox)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        _sendMsgLogBox = sendMsgLogBox;
    }
    .........
}
```

ну а на форма её создавайте, пример

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ........................
    public Form1()
    {
        ...............
        _authenticator = new Authenticator(web, new SendMsgLogBox(this));
        ...............
    }
    ...........................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В конструкторе аутентификатора   создается объект класса `SendMsgLogBox`

```
_sendMsgLogBox = new SendMsgLogBox(null);
```

В конструкторе `SendMsgLogBox` внутреннему полю для взаимодействия с формой присваивается переданное значение - `null`, затем вы пытаетесь у `null` взять текстбокс и положить в  него значение, естественно при этом ловите `NullReferenceException`

Объект класса `SendMsgLogBox` не знает к какой форме обращаться, в текущей реализации при его создании ему нужно передать не `null`, а объект соответствующей формы.

Comment: Можно примером? Никак не могу понять какой объект.

Comment: @АндрейИванов у `_sendMsgLogBox` внутри вместо ссылки на форму с которой работать лежит `null`, при создании ему переданный

Comment: Попробовал вот так, добавил в начале Form1 ff = new Form1(); затем _sendMsgLogBox = new SendMsgLogBox(ff); В итоге открываются бесконечно браузеры, форма даже не выводится.

Comment: @АндрейИванов так зачем каждый раз создавать новую форму? Передавайте в конструктор именно тот объект формы с которым нужно работать.